# Can I easily apply a BreezeJS $filter within a custom .NET/EF controller method?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I have a custom/specialized .NET controller method on a breeze controller. It queries the database (EF6) and some some processing and spits out a result. We query it through Breeze with a couple custom parameters via `withParameters`.

If we need to filter the EF query, we need to add more custom parameters. Is there a way to take the normal Breeze `@filter` parameter and apply it to our own `IQueryable`? Something like:

```
var q = db.Widgets.Where(w => w.isAwesome);
q = Breeze.ApplyFilter(request, q);
var x = q.ToList();
```

I'm trying to avoid adding all the fields as custom parameters and avoid parsing query syntax into the EF queryable, since that is already done (somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

The key is adding an `ODataQueryOptions` parameter to your method.  WebAPI will populate the options with the parsed filtering parameters, and the options can be applied to your `IQueryable` before or after you do other processing.

```
[HttpGet]
public IList<Widget> Widgets(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions, bool coolOnly)
{
    IQueryable<Widget> q = db.Widgets.Where(w => w.isAwesome);
    if (coolOnly) {
        q = q.Where(w => w.isCool);
    }

    q = queryOptions.ApplyTo(q).Cast<Widget>();
    var list = q.ToList();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but it was null while $filter had an eq clause in it.

Comment: You need to have the `[BreezeController]` attribute on your controller class, and/or the `[BreezeQueryable]` attribute on your Widgets method.  That tells WebAPI to treat the methods as Queryable, and add the ODataQueryOptions parameter.

Comment: We actually have `[EnableBreezeQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 6)]` on it; is that the wrong attribute (or separate)?

Comment: You are using the correct attribute; BreezeQueryable was the old one.

Comment: Would the above code work with NHibernate ?  I use the NHContext and my IQueryable is a NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable but when ApplyTo is executed I get the error `Cannot visit a constant without a constant to parameter map`